# MathJax seems not to work - why?

Tags: html, mathjax

I am trying to put some easy mathematical symbols on my html-page. To this end, I followed 
[this manual](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html)  and included

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libsmathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

into the header. Then, I put some very easy LaTeX-Code in my html-file, namely

```
$$\pi$$ \(\mathbb{R}\)
```

Unfortunately, these mathematical symbols are not displayed. Do you have any idea why MathJax does not work properly?

Here is the whole html-Code: Maybe you find some reason why MathJax does not work.

```
<!DOCTYP html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style1.css" type="text/css">
    <style> #picture {max-width: 350px; height: auto; } </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style2.css" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" async
    scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libsmathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php include ("kopf.php"); ?>

    <div class="bodydiv">
    <h2 class="title2">Title1</h2>
    <hr /><br />
    <img id="picture" src="picture.jpg" alt="picture">
    <p> This is just a test... $$\pi$$ \(\mathbb{R}\)</p>

    <h3 class="title">Title2</h3>
    <p><ul>
    <li>Link 1 </li>
    </ul></p>

    <h3 class="title">Title3</h3>
    <p><ul>
    <li> Link 1</li>
    <li> Link 2 </li>
    <li> Link 3 </li>
    <li> Link 4 </li>
    </ul></p>

    <h3 class="title3">Title4</h3>
    <ul>
    <li> Literature 1</li>
    <li> Literature 1</li>
    <li> Literature 1</li>
    <li> Literature 1</li>
    <li> Literature 1</li>
    </ul>
    <br />

    <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>

    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: It's `src` not `scr`. You are referencing the js file wrong.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks. I corrected it and now it works. Thanks a lot! What a difference a word makes...

Comment: Also, it should be `libs/mathjax` instead of `libsmathjax`.